# Nested Drag and Drop using jquery ui not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have developed nested drag drop using jquery ui but it does not allow me to drop outside the
`.drop-container` div. Here is the jsfiddle to review:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wsrbuef7/11/)

Once I drag item and drop it into the #list2 div, it is not working. How can i solve it?

Here is the code:

JS:

```
$(function() {
  $("#list2 .drop-container").sortable({
    connectWith: "#list1",
    over: function() {
      removeIntent = false;
    },
    out: function() {
      removeIntent = true;
    },
    beforeStop: function(event, ui) {
      itemContext = ui.item.context;
      if (removeIntent == true) {
        ui.item.remove();
        disp($("#list2").sortable('toArray'));
      }
      //console.log(itemContext);

    },
    receive: function(event, ui) {
      console.log(ui);
      console.log(event);
      var this_id = $(ui.item).attr("id");
      var preview = $(itemContext).html().replace(/<!--/g, '').replace(/-->/g, '');

      $(itemContext).attr("id", this_id);
      $(itemContext).css("width", $('#list2').width() - 20).addClass("ui-state-default").height('auto');
      $(itemContext).html(preview);

      //console.log(this_id);
      //console.log(preview);

    }
  }); 
  $("#list2").sortable({
connectWith: "#list1",
over: function() {
  removeIntent = false;
},
out: function() {
  removeIntent = true;
},
beforeStop: function(event, ui) {
  itemContext = ui.item.context;
  if (removeIntent == true) {
    ui.item.remove();
    disp($("#list2").sortable('toArray'));
  }
  //console.log(itemContext);

},
receive: function(event, ui) {
  console.log(ui);
  console.log(event);
  var this_id = $(ui.item).attr("id");
  var preview = $(itemContext).html().replace(/<!--/g, '').replace(/-->/g, '');

  $(itemContext).attr("id", this_id);
  $(itemContext).css("width", $('#list2').width() - 20).addClass("ui-state-default").height('auto');
  $(itemContext).html(preview);

  $("#list2 .drop-container").sortable({
    connectWith: "#list1",
    over: function() {
      removeIntent = false;
    },
    out: function() {
      removeIntent = true;
    },
    beforeStop: function(event, ui) {
      itemContext = ui.item.context;
      if (removeIntent == true) {
        ui.item.remove();
        disp($("#list2").sortable('toArray'));
      }
      //console.log(itemContext);

    },
    receive: function(event, ui) {
      console.log(ui);
      console.log(event);
      var this_id = $(ui.item).attr("id");
      var preview = $(itemContext).html().replace(/<!--/g, '').replace(/-->/g, '');

      $(itemContext).attr("id", this_id);
      $(itemContext).css("width", $('#list2').width() - 20).addClass("ui-state-default").height('auto');
      $(itemContext).html(preview);

      //console.log(this_id);
      //console.log(preview);

    }
   }); //.disableSelection()
  //console.log(this_id);
  //console.log(preview);

 }
 }); //.disableSelection()
 $("#list2").bind("sortupdate", function(event, ui) {
//console.log($('#list2'));
var result = $('#list2').sortable('toArray');
var str = '';
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
  str += result[i] + "|";
  var tmp = "#" + result[i] + " .drop-container";
  if ($(tmp).length > 0) {
    $(tmp).each(function() {
      if ($(this).children("li").length) {
        str += $(this).parent()[0].id + "|";
        $(this).children("li").each(function() {
          str += this.id + "|";

        })
      }
    })
  }
} //console.log(result);
alert(str);
});
function disp(list) {
        var a=[];
    for (var i=0;i<list.length;i++){
            a.push(list[i]);
    }
    $( 'input' ).val(a.join('|'));
}

});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="workarea" style="border:1px solid green; width:60%; padding:0; margin:0 0 0 15px;float:left">
        <h3>Your List</h3>
        <ul id="list2" class="connectedSortable ui-sortable" style="width: 100%; min-height: 500px;">
            <li style="width: 500px;" class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle" id="997">
                5.jpg                           
                <span class="pull-right">
                    <div class="text-right hroffset">
                        <a data-toggle="modal" class="preview" ><i class="fa fa fa-eye fa-2x valignmid text-green"></i></a>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="deletemedia"><i class="fa fa-times fa-stack fa-inverse"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </span>
            </li>
            <li style="width: 500px;" class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle" id="998">
                6.jpg                           
                <span class="pull-right">
                    <div class="text-right hroffset">
                        <a data-toggle="modal" class="preview"><i class="fa fa fa-eye fa-2x valignmid text-green"></i></a>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="deletemedia"><i class="fa fa-times fa-stack fa-inverse"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </span>
            </li>
            <li class="ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle" style="width: 500px; height: auto;" id="layoutdata_24_3">
                Layout4                                 
                <span class="pull-right">
                    <div class="text-right">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="deletemedia"><i class="fa fa-times fa-stack fa-inverse"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </span>
                <ul class="layout_panels" style="float:left">
                    <li id="119" data-layout_id="24" style="width: 481px;">
                        <span class="pancls pull-left">Panel: New ( 1360  X 768 ) </span><span class="pull-right"></span>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <ul class="drop-container ui-sortable" style="width: 478px;">
                            <li class="ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-state-default" style="height: auto; width: 477px;" id="1121">
                                <span class="pull-left">1.jpg</span>
                                <span class="pull-right">
                                    <div class="text-right hroffset">
                                        <a data-toggle="modal"class="preview"><i class="fa fa fa-eye fa-2x valignmid text-green"></i></a>
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="deletemedia"><i class="fa fa-times fa-stack fa-inverse"></i></a>
                                    </div>
                                </span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-state-default" style="height: auto; width: 477px;" id="433">
                                <span class="pull-left">2.jpg</span>
                                <span class="pull-right">
                                    <div class="text-right hroffset">
                                        <a data-toggle="modal" class="preview" ><i class="fa fa fa-eye fa-2x valignmid text-green"></i></a>
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="deletemedia"><i class="fa fa-times fa-stack fa-inverse"></i></a>
                                    </div>
                                </span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-state-default" style="height: auto; width: 800px;" id="996" >
                                <span class="pull-left">4.jpg</span>
                                <span class="pull-right">
                                    <div class="text-right hroffset">
                                        <a data-toggle="modal" class="preview" ><i class="fa fa fa-eye fa-2x valignmid text-green"></i></a>
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="deletemedia"><i class="fa fa-times fa-stack fa-inverse"></i></a>
                                    </div>
                                </span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-state-default" style="height: auto; width: 800px;" id="995" >
                                <span class="pull-left">3.jpg</span>
                                <span class="pull-right">
                                    <div class="text-right hroffset">
                                        <a data-toggle="modal" class="preview" ><i class="fa fa fa-eye fa-2x valignmid text-green"></i></a>
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="deletemedia"><i class="fa fa-times fa-stack fa-inverse"></i></a>
                                    </div>
                                </span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Want to drop item outside the panel area. How can i do it? Is there any issue in code?

Comment: Use the built-in UI and  in head instead of ondomready since you have a $(function() there too. What is `disp` by the way. Post some code here too

Comment: disp function is just to reset dropped item that's why not added here.

Comment: Well it blocks the code from executing

Comment: disp function will just pass the array to another input field, nothing else.

Comment: Sheez- not adding it gives ERROR in your fiddle!!!

Comment: updated!!! check now

Comment: @mplungjan: why did you put it as off topic? Without looking for an issue, you guys just put the question in on-hold.Even I have provided fiddle and what I have done and what issue I have. This comm is to help others or to find issues in the question?

Comment: Read the message. It is off topic since it does not contain a [mcve] nor proper explanation of expected and actual functionality. It can be reopened. You even had to fake the fiddle link to bypass SO restrictions

Comment: I have read the message and reopen needs tottal 5 votes. What do you mean by "fake the fiddle link to bypass SO restrictions"?

Comment: I can reopen js questions. When you tried to link to JSFiddle, SO told you it did not allow fiddles without code so you pasted it in as text. Why is it so hard to understand that we do not want to debug incomplete  code and that future users may find a dead link to jsfiddle ? You have so far not received any help because you do not feel like following our instructions

Comment: I have added code in the question.can you also help me to solve the issue?

Comment: Sortable gives error now

Comment: i don't see any error in console.

Comment: There are no more errors - you have a better fiddle now. I have voted for re-open and flagged it too to get it opened faster. Perhaps you delete and re-ask this with all the information we have now

Answer (score -1):

Your Fiddle has a Javascript error since `disp` is not found. You either do not have that `function` here and need to implement it or it exists in your code, but was not added to the Fiddle. Anyway, dragging works, but you need to have a `function` which will display the thing you dropped in the box. Judging from the name, `disp` should be doing that and you will need to either fix or implement it, depending on your situation.

Comment: No disp function is just to reset dropped item that's why not added here.

Comment: @BhumiShah, it causes an error, so you should create a new fiddle and test it to make sure that only the problem you are speaking about is applicable for it. When you are done, let us know about it to help you.